# Proof that $(1-\zeta(1-p,p))/p$ is an integer?

Tags: number-theory, proof-writing, zeta-functions

For all primes $p>2$, does the following identity

$$\frac{1-\zeta(1-p,p)}{p}\in\mathbb{Z}$$

hold such that $\zeta(s,a)$ denotes the Hurwitz zeta function? If so, how would I go about formulating a proof (or is there a proof already in the literature)? Any help would be much appreciated.

The first few values are

[image]

Comment: Hint: $\zeta(s,p)=\zeta(s)-\sum_{k=1}^p{k^{-s}}$. Now take $s=1-p$: $\zeta(1-p)=0$ (standard) so all that remains is $-\sum_{k=1}^p{k^{p-1}}$. Then use FLT.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I assume you are referring to Fermat's Little Theorem, where $\gcd\left(p,\sum_{k=1}^{p-1} k^{p-1}\right)=1$ if $p$ is prime or a Carmichael number. However, it seems that letting $p=561$, produces a rational number see https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281-zeta%281-561%2C+561%29%29%2F561

Comment: Because there are some terms $k^{560}$ with $1 \leq k <561$ is not coprime to $561$.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you very much.

Comment: Another question. Are there any integer values of $n$, such that $\zeta(1-n)\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $n$ is not prime.

Comment: If $n$ is odd $\geq 2$, $\zeta(1-n)=0$.